# Cartoon sci-fi movie about people exploring a planet of dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I saw a cartoon like 10 years ago, I was 10 or so, I’m not sure about the plot but I think there was a group exploring an alien planet, I don't think there was more than 10 of them.

I'm pretty sure it was a 2-d movie and I think there were dinosaurs on the planet they were exploring, but I can't be sure.

The only thing I'm absolutely sure of is a scene:

They were about to go home and one of them, a girl with red hair (I think) decided to stay because home is where the heart is and her heart was there (I'm pretty sure that's the words she used too.)

I'm pretty sure she was more friendiy with the locals than the rest of the team too.

I think she was one of the main characters.

I think they were leaving with a spaceship but I can't be sure of that either.

Comment: This probably isn't it, but the anime Dinosaur King does have a red haired girl and a group exploring an alien land.  It aired in 2007-2009